# Sequence of dates in a vector

Tags: date, sequence

I'm struggling to pimp up a grpah, and would like to create a vector of 3 or 4 dates as character, so that I can include them as labels on the x-axis of my graph; I do not want to specify exact dates, as my dataset might change over years.

What I have:
a tibble with 3 variables as POSIXct, from which I subset the last, as a new tibble named 'data' containing dates

```
data <- structure(list(DT_obs = structure(c(18869, 18870, 18871, 18872, 18873, 18874, 18875, 18876, 18877, 18878, 18879), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -82L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I expect
a vector of 3 or 4 dates, the first, the last and one or two, depending on the length of the vector
`> dates_tab [1] "2021-08-30" "2021-09-04" "2021-09-09"`

What I tried
I tried using seq() and seq.Date() with first(data) and last(data) as arguments, but it did not work, as first(data) and last(data) get me the full dataset, and not only the first or last value. Maybe is the dataset 'data' not in the right format?

thanks for your help =)